# JMP file - post subscription

Tags: excel, statistics, sas, sas-jmp

I was at a university the used the Stats program JMP. I have since left and want to access the data I was working on but I can't open the file as my subscription to the software has finished. Is there anyway I can access the data (change it to an text or excel file, for example) with some programming wizardry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a free trial of the software [here](http://www.jmp.com/software/try-jmp.shtml?product=jmp) and open your JMP files. Save AS to Excel format. Worst case upload your file to web and share link and see if someone with JMP can convert for you.

I have tried converting JMP files to Excel without the program and was not successful- not sure it can be done.